# Scraped items for pagination links are not usual href

Tags: python, web-scraping, http-post

When i run my scraper to get the href link for next page i can see that it fetches [javascript: void(0);] instead of conventional href. I can't make use of it anyway. Would be very happy if someone takes a look into it and provides me with a workaround. The code I'm using:

```
import requests
from lxml import html
url="http://www.findanarchitect.com.au/index.php"
def Endpoint(Address):
    payload = {'action':'show_search_result','action_spam':'dDfgEr','txtSearchType':5,'txtPracName':'','optSstate':3,'optRegions':23,'txtPcode':'','txtShowBuildingType':0,'optBuildingType':1,'optHomeType':1,'optBudget':''}
    response = requests.post(Address, data = payload)
    tree=html.fromstring(response.text)
    titles=tree.xpath('//div[@id="pagination"]')
    for title in titles:
        Links=title.xpath('.//li[@class]/a/@href')
        for Link in Links:
            print(Link)

Endpoint(url)
```

Html elements residing within:

```
<div id="pagination">
<br><div style="float:left">Page 1 of 23 &nbsp;</div>
<ul>
    <li class="current"><a href="javascript: void(0);" onclick="js_goto_page(1)">1</a></li><li class=""><a href="javascript: void(0);" onclick="js_goto_page(2)">2</a></li><li class=""><a href="javascript: void(0);" onclick="js_goto_page(3)">3</a></li><li class=""><a href="javascript: void(0);" onclick="js_goto_page(4)">4</a></li><li class=""><a href="javascript: void(0);" onclick="js_goto_page(5)">5</a></li><li class=""><a href="javascript: void(0);" onclick="js_goto_page(6)">6</a></li><li class=""><a href="javascript: void(0);" onclick="js_goto_page(7)">7</a></li><li class=""><a href="javascript: void(0);" onclick="js_goto_page(8)">8</a></li><li class=""><a href="javascript: void(0);" onclick="js_goto_page(9)">9</a></li><li class=""><a href="javascript: void(0);" onclick="js_goto_page(10)">10</a></li><li class=""><a href="javascript: void(0);" onclick="js_goto_page(11)">[11-20]</a></li><li class=""><a href="javascript: void(0);" onclick="js_goto_page(21)">[21-23]</a></li>
</ul>

</div>
```

The result I'm getting:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `js_go_to_page` function is present on the html

```
/*
* Go to Page
*/
function js_goto_page(page_no)
{
    $('#idCurPageNo').val(page_no);
    action = "action=ajax_goto_page";
    furl = '/index.php?'+action+'&page_no='+page_no+'&search_type='+$('#idSubSearchType').val();
    $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url:furl,
            cache :false,
            async:false,
            dataType:'json',
            success: function(data)
                    {
                        $('#archWrapper').html(data.html);
                        $('#pagination_bottom').html(data.pagination_tab); 
                        //$("html").animate({ scrollTop: 0 });
                        $("html").scrollTop(0);

                    }
        });
}
```

You need to reproduce the content of `furl` variable on your crawler code, which is pretty strightforward as `action`is static, `page_no` is the number of the page you want to get and `$('#idSubSearchType').val()`can be read with the html parser.

Comment: Thanks VMRuiz, for you answer. My head is spinning to see your code. Is it written in javascript? I've already rectified my post by discarding javascript tag because coding in javascript is beyond my capability.

Comment: Yes, Its javascript but you dont need to code anything on it. You just need to generate the URL for the next page the same way as they do on that script. Look at the line with `furl`